# Site Navigation and links hide/unhide based on permissions

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a application using asp.net (C#) and this time the design concept is two frame based master page like left side will have navigation and right side frame will have content pages.

The navigation will have menu like the following.

1. System Parameters
   ........ Customer Setup
   ........ Currency Setup
   ........ User Management Setup
   ........ Group Definition
2. Transactions
    ..... Transaction 1
    ..... Transaction 2
    ..... Transaction 3

In Group Management I want to assign access permissions on forms and place users into the groups. Now my question is how to hide/unhide navigation links based on the group permission of logged in user.

I want to come up with the application design like the following

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/17/435765.aspx

Please guide how to handle dynamic menu and build this type of application and restrict users not access the page on which he/she has no permission...most of the solutions over internet is based on web.config where roles are defined but I want to keep my roles in database along with the group permissions. so need solution based on database.

Answer (score 0):

first, once a user logs in, you can store his/her authorisation level in a session variable. E.g. `Session("CurrentUserLevel")="admin"`

then,

### to hide navigation items, you can write code to do:

```
if session("CurrentUserLevel") <> "admin" then
customerSetup.visible = false ' where customerSetup is your asp.net element
end if
```

to prevent pages from being accessed, place a code on top of each page:

```
if Session("CurrentUserLevel") <> "admin" Then Response.Redirect("hope.aspx")
```

note: this is a very simple and static/hard coded solution. Usually, you should use more advanced techniques to accomplish such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

you gonna refer to the control via master page then change its visibility to current user 
like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["id"]!=null)
        {
            liberarianDrop.SelectedValue = (Session["id"].ToString());
          ((LinkButton)this.Master.FindControl("LoginBtn")).Visible = false;}

    }
```